# Zend Framework 2 "Zend Tool Missing" in bin folder

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-tool

im newbie in frameworks, but i had no difficulty installing etc the zend 1.x versions. But with ZF2 cant really figure out.... 
Any recource telling me creating a project using the zend tool i.e. zf.bat or zf.sh from bin directory, but there's none of them in the zf2 bin folder in contrast to zf1. The only files present are

```
autloader_example.php 
autloader_examples.php 
classmap_generator.php 
createAuoloadTestClasses.php 
docbook_skeleton.php 
plugin_generator.php
```

can anyone help me anyhow... neet it asap

thanx. 
d

Answer (score 15):

Because Zend Framework 2 are under development, this time, we have not a tool to automate code generation, but, you can download a Application Skeleton from:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Which is a

> Simple skeleton application using the ZF2 MVC layer and module
>   systems. This application is meant to be used as a starting place for
>   those looking to get their feet wet with ZF2.

Comment: thanx a lot, saved my time;)... ill dig into it

Answer (score 0):

Zend tool component currently under development like framework's itself.

Anyway after created a skeleton app like Gabriel's said, you can try to manage your modules using zftool. It provides limited but working functionality.

Check out zftool here:
https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool