# Cant find zf.bat in zend framework download

Tags: php, zend-framework2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend Framework 2 “Zend Tool Missing” in bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778626/zend-framework-2-zend-tool-missing-in-bin-folder)

I am trying to install the zend framework on my computer and it seems that I need a file zf.bat and its supposed to be in the bin folder. All that I have in the bin folder is:

autoload_example.php
autoload_examples.php
classmap_generator.php
createAutoloadTestClasses.php
pluginmap_generator.php

I know that this isn't a programming question, so can someone help me direct it to the correct forum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no more zf.bat

start from this http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no Zend_Tool in Zend Framework 2. You just copy the Skeleton Application (for the time being).

In ZF1 there definetely IS zf.bat in the bin directory. Double check you're downloading ZF1 and double check the contents of the archive.